# React native + react-native-router-flux + AsyncStorage: how i move between scenes in different routers

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux, asyncstorage

In React Native using `react-native-router-flux` and `AsyncStorage`, I have several scenes spread over several routers, and I need to move from any scene to the auth scene when the session has expired (for many reasons, token expired, logout, etc ..)

this is my main router [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfPJL.png)

```js
export default class RouterComponent extends Component<{}> {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {hasToken: false, isLoaded: false};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    AsyncStorage.getItem('authtoken').then((token) => {
      console.log(token);
      this.setState({hasToken: token !== null, isLoaded: true})
    });
  }


  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoaded) {
      return (
        <ActivityIndicator/>
      )
    } else {
      return (
        <Router cerrarSesion={this.cerrarSesion}>
        <Scene key="root">
          <Scene key="auth">
            <Scene key="login" component={Login} hideNavBar initial={!this.state.hasToken}/>
            <Scene key="recuperarPass" component={RecuperarPass} hideNavBar/>
            <Scene key="seleccionarSucursal" component={SeleccionarSucursal} hideNavBar/>
          </Scene>

          <Scene key="main" initial={this.state.hasToken}>
            <Scene key="appContainer" component={AppContainer} hideNavBar/>
          </Scene>

          <Scene key="activador">
            <Scene key="activadorRegistrar" component={RegistrarUsuario} hideNavBar/>
          </Scene>
        </Scene>
        </Router>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

This is my appContainer component [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGLrg.png)

```js
export default class AppContainer extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      data: this.props.data,
      authtoken: this.props.authtoken,
      sucursal: this.props.sucursal
    };
  }


  componentWillMount() {
    this.getDataFromStorage();
  }

  async getDataFromStorage() {
    try {
      let value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('authtoken');
      if (value !== null) {
        this.setState({authtoken: value});
        AsyncStorage.getItem('authtoken').then((data) => {
          this.setState({data});
          console.log('data en asyncstorage:' + this.state.data);
          console.log('authtoken en asyncstorage:' + this.state.authtoken);
        });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      // Error retrieving data
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.state.data);
    console.log(this.state.authtoken);

  }

  render(props) {
    console.log(this.props.sucursal);
    return (
      <View style={styles.bigContainer}>
      <Header/>
      <MainContainer data={this.state.data} authtoken={this.state.authtoken} sucursal={this.state.sucursal}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my `mainContainer`, another router inside my main router [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7YIY.png)

```js
export default class MainContainer extends Component<{}> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      datalogin: this.props.data,
      authtoken: this.props.authtoken,
      sucursal: this.props.sucursal
    };
  }



  async cerrarSesion(mensaje) {
    try {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem('id_token');
      Alert.alert(mensaje);
      Actions.auth()
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('AsyncStorage error: ' + error.message);
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router {...this.state} cerrarSesion={this.cerrarSesion}  hideNavBar>
        <Scene key="buscarUsuario" component={BuscarUsuario} initial/>
        <Scene key="resultadoBusqueda" component={ResultadoBusqueda}/>
        <Scene key="historialTransacciones" component={HistorialTransacciones}/>
        <Scene key="registrarUsuario" component={RegistrarUsuario}/>
        <Scene key="redimirRegalos" component={RedimimirRegalos}/>
        <Scene key="cambiarPass" component={CambiarPass}/>
        <Scene key="informacion" component={Informacion}/>
        <Scene key="sideBar" component={Sidebar}/>
        <Scene key="premiosComercio" component={ListaPremiosComercio}/>
        <Scene key="vincular" component={VincularUsuario}/>
        <Scene key="router" component={MyRouter}/>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

This is my sidebar component, it's inside my `mainContainer` and here where I close my session [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tWxq9.png)

```js
render () {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.sideBarHeader}>
        <Image style={styles.image} source={require('../../images/prueba.png')}/>
        <Text style={styles.titleText} >Nombre Completo</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.sideBarBody}>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            type="flatSidebar"
            onPress={() => this.onClick('buscar_usuario')}>Buscar usuario</Button>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            type="flatSidebar"
            onPress={() => this.onClick('agregar_usuario')}>Agregar nuevo usuario</Button>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            type="flatSidebar"
            onPress={() => this.onClick('informacion')}>Información</Button>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            type="flatSidebar"
            onPress={() => this.onClick('cambiar_pass')}>Cambiar Contraseña</Button>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
          <Button
            type="flatSidebar"
            onPress={() => this.props.cerrarSesion('Sesion cerrada Correctamente')}>Cerrar Sesión</Button>
        </View>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

This is one of the many components where I evaluate if the token expired, all of them are in `mainContainer` [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqWta.png)

```js
async requestUsuarios (formdata) {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://*************************', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        '**************': ****************,
      },
      body: formdata
    });
    const responseJson = await response.json();
    return responseJson;
  }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    this.props.cerrarSesion('Error en el servidor, inicie sesion nuevamente');
  }
}
```

I want that every time a condition is fulfilled (logout button, token expired, etc) I can call the method that passed from app container and redirect to the login, but the following message always comes out [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8A7v.png)

> [react-native-router-flux] missed route data for key=auth

Comment: I like that you've got a lot of code here, but on SO we prefer that you paste (and format) the actual code into your question so the question remains useful long after your image links die.

Comment: @jmargolisvt thanks for the recommendations, i edit the question and include the code in it, sorry for my bad english XD